# Login with facebook Using ACAccountStore is not working in ios 9.2.1

Tags: objective-c, ios9, slcomposeviewcontroller, acaccountstore, ios9.2.1

Here is my code to login with facebook :

```
   if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook])
        {
            ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
            ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];
            NSDictionary *options = @{ACFacebookAppIdKey : FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
                                      ACFacebookPermissionsKey : @[@"public_profile"]
                                      };
            [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType
                                                  options:options
                                               completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
             {

                 if(granted)
                 {
    }
                 else
                 {
                     NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
    }
             }]; 
}
```

When I am trying to login with facebook in iOS 9.2.1 the **"granted"** parameter always become false. I have tried in other versions like iOS 9.2 and iOS 9.1 it working fine

I have made lots of R&D in stack and also in google but not able to find proper solution.

Your help would be appreciable.

Thanks.